# Bad visualization on IE 8

Tags: theming, media

I developed a site using Drupal, and it's the first time that I create my own theme, subtheming the Zen theme.

If you try to go to www.garnisellacipriani.it with firefox or chrome, the visualization is perfect. If you try with IE, the banner with the images is not shown!

What can it be?

Thank you very much,
Alessandro

Comment: I know I'm using Windows 8, but it seems fine in IE 8 mode. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/qoRhU0h.jpg)

Comment: Buongiorno amico! I tried the website on Windows 7, IE10 and IE9 and IE8 and it worked well on all those modes. What version of IE and Windows are you using that gives you that error Alessandro?

Comment: I've tested it in IE 10/9/8/7 and it works properly in each one.  What you can try in IE is push f12 and click the 'console' tab to see if there are any javascript errors.  Then we can narrow it down if you see a problem there.